# Ordenar y Multiplicar valores obtenidos de Python a un CSV

Tags: python, tkinter, csv

Tengo un pequeño programa que registra datos de diferentes productos y con los datos obtenidos genera un CSV.

Lo que me gustaría que hiciera es que en el Entry de **Peso en gr:** la cantidad obtenida se multiplique *.10

Además que los 3 valores obtenidos ***"Producto, Peso en gr y Cantidad"*** se acomoden cada una en una columna.

Por Ejemplo: ***Producto*** en columna 1, ***Peso en gr*** en columna 2, etc...

Aquí abajo adjunto mi código, Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias!

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("290x290")
root.config(bg="salmon")

def Datos():    
  Entry1_info = Entry1.get()
  Entry2_info = Entry2.get()
  Entry3_info = Entry3.get()
      
  file = open("Datos1.csv", "a") 
  file.write("Producto: "+ Entry1_info)
  file.write("\n")
  file.write("Peso en gr: "+Entry2_info)
  file.write("\n")
  file.write("Cantidad: "+Entry3_info)
  file.close()
  
Entry1 = StringVar()
Entry2 = StringVar()
Entry3 = StringVar()
        
        
Frame1 = Frame(root, bd=2, padx=10, pady=3)

Label(Frame1, text="Producto: ", font=('Times', 14)).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, pady=10)
Label(Frame1, text="Peso en gr: ", font=('Times', 14)).grid(row=2, column=0,sticky=W, pady=10)
Label(Frame1, text="Cantidad: ", font=('Times', 14)).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=10)

Entry11 = Entry(Frame1,textvariable = Entry1, width=5).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W, pady=10)
Entry22 = Entry(Frame1,textvariable = Entry2, width=5).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W, pady=10)
Entry33 = Entry(Frame1,textvariable = Entry3, width=5).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=10)

Boton1 = Button(Frame1, text="Generar CSV", width=10, command= Datos).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W, pady=10)

Frame1.place(x=20, y=40)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si vas a manejar algún archivo (que no sea txt) es mejor usar algún módulo que te ayude, en mi caso voy a utilizar `pandas` ya que es muy simple armar un csv con el, además tiene diversos métodos para hacerlo.

**instalación**

```
pip install pandas
```

**código**

```
import os #nos servira para luego
import pandas
... #demas imports
```

Para armar nuestro csv usaremos un método de pandas para crear un DataFrame el cual al final lo exportaremos como `csv`. Una de las formas de crear un *DataFrame* es con diccionarios `{colunm: [value]}` donde `colunm` es el nombre de la columna y su valor será una lista de n valores.

```py
def Datos():    
  Entry1_info = Entry1.get()
  Entry2_info = Entry2.get()
  Entry3_info = Entry3.get()
  
  #convertimos a entero y multiplicamos
  Entry2_info = int(Entry2_info)*3 #si tambien quieres decimales usa float()

  #creamos diccionario
  data = {"Producto":[Entry1_info], "Peso en gr": [Entry2_info], "Cantidad": [Entry3_info]}  

  #convertimos a DataFrame
  archivo = pd.DataFrame(data)
  archivo.to_csv("Data1.csv", mode="a", header= not os.path.isfile("Data1.csv"))
```

Aquí hay algo interesante, pues en la ultima linea de la función se le pasa 2 parámetros adicionales `mode` y `header`. El parámetro `mode` indica el modo en como va a ser abierto el archivo, los cuales son los mismos modos que en la función `open()` (`a`, `r`, `w`, etc) Aqui le indicamos `"a"` para que en caso exista el archivo añada los nuevos valores y no los sobrescriba.

El parámetro `header` permite especificar si las llaves del diccionario serán los nombres de las columnas, se puede especificar:

- una lista de cadenas.
- `True`: Usa como nombre las claves del diccionario
- `False`: No escribe el nombre de las columnas

En este caso utilizamos el modulo `os` y su método `isfile()` para comprobar si el archivo existe, ya que si existe y le ponemos `header=True` las columnas se añadirán como datos. `isfile()` devuelve `True` en caso existe, en ese caso no quieres escribir los `headers` por eso se niega la expresión con `not`.

Comment: Christian te agradezco muchísimo tu ayuda, me ha funcionado a pedir de boca. Solo una cosa más, ¿Como puedo hacer para eliminar la columna A en el csv, ya que en ella se muestran 0?

Comment: en tu código no he visto una columna `a`, pero si se muestran números ascendentes (como un id), puedes agregar el parámetro `index=None` al momento de exportar el csv